# Inject config.yml settings into service

Tags: symfony

I have some settings in my `config.yml` that I would like to pass as an argument to a service in `services.yml`.

```
#config.yml
hwi_oauth:
resource_owners:
        facebook:
            type:                facebook
            client_id:           %facebook_app_id%
            client_secret:       %facebook_app_secret%
            scope:               "email, public_profile, user_friends"
            infos_url:     "https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,email,picture.type(square)"
            paths:
                email:          email
                profilepicture: picture.data.url
            options:
                display: popup #dialog is optimized for popup window


#services.yml
hwi_oauth.resource_owner.facebook:
      class: AppBundle\OAuth\ResourceOwner\FacebookResourceOwner
      arguments: ['@hwi_oauth.http_client','@security.http_utils',**{INJECT HERE}**,'@hwi_oauth.storage.session']
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

Make these values as parameters. You can inject parameters into service.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without manually entering them...? what would be the point in having it in the config.yml then

Comment: Parameters are machine specific options and config should be environment specific.

You can setParameters from Extensions:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html#using-the-load-method
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/prepend_extension.html